# Gadfly Histogram Appears to Select the Wrong Support

Tags: histogram, julia, gadfly

I am new to [Julia](http://julialang.org/), and I am exploring the ways in which I can visualize distributions.  Ultimately, I may fall back on the more robust [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) code base, but I really enjoy the dynamic visualization element that [IJulia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl) offers in the [Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html).

My issue concerns plotting histograms of proportional values with [Gadfly](http://dcjones.github.io/Gadfly.jl/).  I am able to plot the kernel density with Gadfly automatically selecting a reasonable support (a.k.a. one consistent with the underlying data: [-0.1,0.5]).

```
#Visualization
using Gadfly

#(Python) pandas analogue
require("DataFrames")

#Practice sets
require("RDatasets")

#Extract the Hedonic set
hedonic=RDatasets.dataset("plm","Hedonic")

#Define density plot layer for black population proportion
dens_layer=layer(hedonic,x=:Blacks,Geom.density,Theme(default_color=color("#de2d26")))

#Plot kernel density
dens_plot=plot(dens_layer, Guide.title("Distribution of Black Proportion"))
```

[image]

The histogram plot, however, is fit to a support that is far too large ([0,4]).  All of the relevant data are captured by a single bar that spans the entire [0,1] interval.

```
#Define histogram layer
hist_layer=layer(hedonic,x=:Blacks,Geom.histogram,Theme(default_color=color("#de2d26"))) 

#Plot histogram
hist_plot_default=plot(hist_layer, Guide.title("Distribution of Black Proportion"))
```

[image]

When I increase the `bincount`, the support just grows.  For example, with `bincount=100`, the support grows to [0,150], with all of the data still represented by a single bar.

```
#Plot histogram again, this time with 100 bins
hist_plot_bin100=plot(hedonic,x=:Blacks,Geom.histogram(bincount=100),Theme(default_color=color("#de2d26")))
```

[image]

So, if anyone can tell me what I am screwing up, it would certainly be appreciated.  Alternatively, perhaps restricting the range would force the appropriate allocation of histogram bars...?   To that end, how do I restrict the range so that I can view the distribution on the [0,1] interval?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed, please see the below results for your example,

```
julia> using Gadfly, DataFrames, RDatasets
julia> hedonic=RDatasets.dataset("plm","Hedonic")
julia> hist_layer=layer(hedonic,x=:Blacks,Geom.histogram,Theme(default_color=color("#de2d26")))
julia> hist_plot_default=plot(hist_layer, Guide.title("Distribution of Black Proportion"))
```

[image]

```
julia> hist_plot_bin100=plot(hedonic,x=:Blacks,Geom.histogram(bincount=100),Theme(default_color=color("#de2d26")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can recreate this. I think it goes down this branch in the code

https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/040606f82c4e014611464068b0d5cda111b6662a/src/statistics.jl#L136-L143

```
    isdiscrete = false
    value_set = collect(Set(values[Bool[Gadfly.isconcrete(v) for v in values]]))
    sort!(value_set)


    if  length(value_set) / length(values) < 0.9
        d, bincounts, x_max = choose_bin_count_1d_discrete(
                    values, value_set, stat.minbincount, stat.maxbincount)
```

which is odd as it isn't discrete data, and shouldn't be discrete bins. If it uses the `choose_bin_count_1d` instead it gets much more sensible answers. I think the thing with `bincount` changing the support is a related bug probably, but not sure how that happens. You should file an issue on the Gadfly github page.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, it's informative to know I am not the only one with this result.  I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/435) (#435).

Comment: scanning `choose_bin_count_1d_discrete`, it seems the calculation of mingap uses the indices instead of the values at:
`mingap = mingap == zero(eltype(xs)) ? b - a : min(b - a, mingap)`.
better post this in the open issue.

Comment: That stood out to me too, I assume it makes more sense for actually discrete data,